# symfony twig : add a class while keeping the existing ones

Tags: symfony, templates, merge, twig

In a template, I am using the following code to add a class to an element :

```
{% set attr = field.vars.attr|merge({'class':'input-sm'}) %} 
{{ dump(attr) }}
{{ form_widget(field, attr) }}
```

the dump shows the array with the input-sm class but the control does not have it.
If I do it without the merge, the classes defined in my type are overriden, and I don't want that, I want to keep both classes defined in my type and defined in my template.

Does someone knows how to solve this?

EDIT:
I corrected a first mistake. But then the classes defined in my type are overriden

```
{% set attr = field.vars.attr|merge({'class':'input-sm'}) %}
{{ form_widget(field, {'attr' : attr}) }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

Solution :

```
    {% if field.vars.attr['class'] is defined %}
        {% set class = field.vars.attr['class'] ~ ' input-sm' %}
    {% else %}
        {% set class = 'input-sm' %}
    {% endif %}
    {% set attr = field.vars.attr|merge({'class': class }) %}
    {{ form_widget(field, {'attr' : attr}) }}
```